# PHP spacing between floated div containing SQL results (paged) and another div containing content

Tags: php, mysql, css-float, spacing

I am having a problem where I have made a database that contains 7 items. These items are displayed by echoing a variable and set to page in sets of 3. I have some content under the div that displays the results. Each one of the items displays in its own div within the div holding the results. Each result div (item) is floated left.

On the first two pages, this content appears directly under the results. On the last page, I can see the space in between the results and the content; the space is the 
 tag that i inserted to try and put some between the results and the content below it.

I tried adding bottom padding and margins to the container div but this still will only display on the last page.

My question, is how can I do this in a better way, so that i can actually add spacing between the container div and the contents below it on all pages?

Comment: TURN OFF YOUR CAPS LOCK!  IT LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE SHOUTING!  ENTERING YOUR QUESTION IN CAPS WON'T MAKE IT MORE LIKELY THAT YOU'LL GET AN ANSWER!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you styling the divs on the same page or in a template? can we get some of the code to look at, would help out a bit.